# When I try to print the value pointed by a pointer of a pointer I get null

Tags: c

As a homework I need to rewrite the string.h library, I have started with the strcat function but I am having trouble printing the **dest variable.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef MY_STRING_H
#define MY_STRING_H

int my_strlen(char *str){
    int count;
    for (count = 0; str[count] != '\0'; ++count);
    return count; 
}
 
void my_strcat(char **dest, const char *src){
    size_t srcSize = my_strlen((char *)src);
    size_t destSize = my_strlen((char *)dest);
    dest = realloc(dest ,(destSize + srcSize) * sizeof(char));
    int count;

    printf("%s \n", (char *) dest); //prints null here

    for (count = 0; dest[count] != '\0'; ++count); //throws segmentation error here
    for (int count2=0; src[count2] != '\0'; ++count2){
        *dest[count] = src[count2];
        count += 1;
    }
    *dest[count] += '\0';
}
 
int main (){
  char str[80] = "these strings";
  my_strcat ((char **) str,"are ");
  my_strcat ((char **) str,"concatenated.");
  printf("%s", str);
  return 0;
}

#endif // MY_STRING_H
```

I dont know how I can fix this please help me.

Comment: _"As a homework I need to rewrite the string.h library,"_ - that seems excessive for undergraduate-level homework - do you really and literally mean that you're expected to reimplement everything in that file, including `memcpy`, `memmove`, strerror`, etc?

Comment: @Dai well of course not everything sorry for the confusion but I only need to rewrite 4 functions in that library: `strcat` `strstr_match` `strspn` and `strtok`

Comment: Why is the first param of `my_strcat(char **dest,` a double pointer rather than a single pointer?

Comment: @AviBerger unfortunately that is a boiler plate given by the school website so I have to work with it I guess?

Comment: ...I hope the reason the assignment asks you to reimplement `strtok` so that you know why you shouldn't use it :)

Comment: @BotEllis A `strcat` function using `char** dest` would be _nothing like_ C Std's `strcat` because it implies the responsibility of allocation is the callee's, not the caller's, which is the opposite of the real `strcat`, in which case I question the didactic value of this exercise...

Comment: @Dai I think the reason you are talking about is that it changes the pointed char.

Comment: Actually, I now see that the reason is that your my_strcat() is not a straight reimplementation of strcat(). It requires that the first parameter is a pointer to a pointer to malloc'ed memory & realloc's it to the right size. This means that your calls to it in main that pass str are invalid, as they do not meet the function's requirements.

Comment: @BotEllis Not only that, but also because `strtok` isn't reentrant (because it mutates hidden state).  There's a _lot_ of just-plain-_bad_ stuff in C. How can we forget `gets` is a thing?

Comment: You would need a char *malloced_ptr = malloc( some_number); in main and pass &malloced_ptr to my_strcat(). And copy some null terminated string into the buffer before passing it. Presuming I'm making the right guesses based on what you posted.

Comment: BTW, your `my_strlen` should use `size_t count`, not `int` - and you might want to consider adding an assertion that `str != NULL` - and given the sheer size of 64-bit memory-space I'd also consider adding a sanity-check that asserts `count` never goes over something unreasonably large, like a couple of megabytes - otherwise a freak-accident-of-memory could cause your program to iterate over gigabytes of nonzero bytes of memory (and your `count` would overflow too).

Comment: `printf("%s", str);` <-- For trivial printing, consider using `puts` instead.

Comment: The original strcat is defined similar to `strcat(char *dest, const char *src)` which is rather different from your `my_strcat(char **dest, const char *src)`. Please explain why you want to do it differently. Also please bear in mind that **every** cast you have potentially masks a serious error. Your program should contain zero casts, and compile with [zero warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings). If you are having trouble with writing a program this way and a cast seems like the only solution, stop and **ask a question**.

Comment: When you say *"boiler plate given by the school website"*, do you mean that you *have* to mantain the signatures `int my_strlen(char *str)` and `void my_strcat(char **dest, const char *src)` of those function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my_strcat(), you used a char ** pointer while you transfer a char * pointer, maybe you can use (char *)dest.

(Also, since you have a my_strlen() function, you don't need a for loop to get the length of array.)

in this case, i tried to fix it like :

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef MY_STRING_H
#define MY_STRING_H

int my_strlen(char *str){
    int count;
    for (count = 0; str[count] != '\0'; ++count);
    return count; 
}
 
void my_strcat(char **dest, const char *src){
    size_t srcSize = my_strlen((char *)src);
    size_t destSize = my_strlen((char *)dest);
    dest = realloc(dest ,(srcSize+destSize) * sizeof(char));
    int count;
    int count2=0;
    printf("%s\n", (char *) dest); //prints null here
    for (count=0 ;((char *)dest)[count]!='\0'; ++count); //throws segmentation error here
    for (; src[count2] != '\0'; ++count2){
        ((char *)dest)[count] = src[count2];
        count += 1;
    }
    ((char *)dest)[count] += '\0';
}
 
int main (){
  char str[80] = "these strings";
  my_strcat ((char **) str,"are ");
  my_strcat ((char **) str,"concatenated.");
  printf("%s", str);
  return 0;
}

#endif // MY_STRING_H
```

By chance, i noticed that if replace `printf("%s\n", (char *) dest)` to `printf("%s \n", (char *) dest)`, something wrong will happen. Amazing! I tried to read assembly code to found the difference between two code, and i find that for the first printf, it will be compilered into puts while the second will be compilered into printf with "%s \n" compilered into a string. I haven't know what happened now.

Then, suddenly, i think that we transfer a pointer `str` which point to data in stack, while it seems we need a pointer point to data in heap.

i tried some simple code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main (){
  char str[80] = "these strings";
  printf("%lld\n", str);

  void * p = realloc(str ,100 * sizeof(char));
  printf("%lld", &((char *)p)[4]);
  return 0;
}
```

it works well.
however, in:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main (){
  char str[80] = "these strings";
  printf("%lld\n", str);

  char str1[80] = "these strings";
  printf("%lld\n", str1);

  void * p = realloc(str ,100 * sizeof(char));
  printf("%lld", &((char *)p)[4]);
  return 0;
}
```

it can't work.
then:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main (){
  char * str = (char *)malloc(80);
  str[0] = 'h'; str[1] = 'i'; str[2] = '\0';
  printf("%lld\n", str);

  char str1[80] = "these strings";
  printf("%lld\n", str1);

  void * p = realloc(str ,100 * sizeof(char));
  printf("%lld", &((char *)p)[4]);
  return 0;
}
```

it works well.

so, it seems you can't get str by this way, for the pointer transfered into `realloc()` should be alloced  by `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`. In another word, this pointer should point to data in heap. You can see this in [realloc - cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc). When i change the way we get str by malloc, it works well. You can try this.

At last, from the args of `my_strcat()`, i think maybe you should change the way you implement this function.

I haven't written C code for a long time, hope this can help you.